# Kendo Grid Client Detail Template Local Data Binding

Tags: data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-listview

I have a Kendo Grid with a Kendo ListView for its client detail template.
Here is the grid :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ITS.BusinessModel.TaskManager.TaskItem>()
        .Name("grdPackage" + Model + "sTasks")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(taskModel => taskModel.WorkflowInstanceId);
            columns.Bound(taskModel => taskModel.WorkflowInstanceName);
            columns.Bound(taskModel => taskModel.Name).ClientTemplate("<a onclick='openTasksForm(#= ID#)' > #= Name # </a>");
        }
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("TaskSumeriesListViewTemplate")
        .AutoBind(false)
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(20)
            .ServerOperation(true)
            .Model(model => model.Id(Task => Task.ID))
            .Read(read => read.Action("TaskItemsList_Read", "Task", new { packageGroupID = Model, packageType = (Model == -2) ? 0 : (Model == -1) ? 1 : 2 }))
        )
)
```

Here is the client template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="TaskSumeriesListViewTemplate">

    @(Html.Kendo().ListView<ITS.BusinessModel.TaskManager.WorkflowInstanceSummaryItem>("#=TaskSumaries#")
        .Name("listViewPackage")
        .TagName("div")
        .ClientTemplateId("SummeriesTemplate")
        .ToClientTemplate()
        )
</script>
```

And here is the template for ListView :

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="SummeriesTemplate">
    <div>
        #=ColumnName# : #=ColumnValue#
    </div>
</script>
```

Each TaskItem that Grid reads has a TaskSumariesList which is a List.
I want to use this list in Grid Client Detail for ListView.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

In your Events call for your grid, use something like this:

```
.Events(e => e.DetailInit("detailInit")
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
function detailInit(e) {
    var list= $("#listViewPackage").data("kendoGrid");      

    list.dataSource.data(e.data.TaskSumariesList) 
}
```

What will happen is that the list will get populated with the appropriate data when it expands.

You may need to do something like this for your List name:

```
.Name("listViewPackage#=WorkflowInstanceId#")
```

This way, you can make sure you have the right data for the right list:

```
function detailInit(e) {
    var list= $("#listViewPackage" + e.data.WorkflowInstanceId).data("kendoGrid");      

    list.dataSource.data(e.data.TaskSumariesList) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answering Sean

I dont understand your way.
I want  to open a ListView for each item in GridView.
In my model i have all I want.
For each item in my model that I show in GridView , I have a List For It's Details.
For Solving , I had to post each detailsItem of each Item of GridView to server and again posting it to client to open ListView in GridViewDetail .
But I want to do it without posting .

Answer (score 0):

Actually Sean is right. For more information please refer:
[Kendo UI Grid: Detail Template Binding](http://blog.falafel.com/kendo-ui-grid-detail-template-binding/)

You can also add **DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax())** to your seccond grid.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<ITS.BusinessModel.TaskManager.WorkflowInstanceSummaryItem>("#=TaskSumaries#")
        .Name("listViewPackage")
        .TagName("div")
        .ClientTemplateId("SummeriesTemplate")
        .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()) 
        .ToClientTemplate()
        )
```

It seems like Client template is not available for local bound grids.